# Celery Task not getting assigned through redis

Tags: python, django, redis, celery

Using Celery/redis i tried creating a task, But on checking the celery working info with the below code
`celery -A intranet_project worker -l info`
I am unable to get the task added there.

Settings.py

```
BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://localhost:6379'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['application/json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TIMEZONE = TIME_ZONE
```

**init**.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

# This will make sure the app is always imported when
# Django starts so that shared_task will use this app.
from .celery import app as celery_app

__all__ = ('celery_app',)
```

celery.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
import os
from celery import Celery
from django.conf import settings

# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'intranet_project.settings')
app = Celery('intranet_project')

# Using a string here means the worker will not have to
# pickle the object when using Windows.
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
app.autodiscover_tasks()


@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

my_task.py

```
from celery.decorators import task
from celery import shared_task

@shared_task
def add(a,b):
    d = a + b
    return d
```

Below is the server log

[tasks]
  . intranet_project.celery.debug_task

[2020-02-26 19:38:59,051: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to redis://localhost:6379//
[2020-02-26 19:38:59,160: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
[2020-02-26 19:39:00,379: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: all alone

Comment: How are you calling your task? appaerently is everything well set. Remember to user the async call `.delay()` when calling your task. e.g. `add.delay(2, 3)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don`t see the code from where you execute your task.

**view.py** (or wherever you want to trigger the task from)

```
from .my_tasks import add

def action(request):
    add.delay(2,2)
```

You should then see a line like this appear in your celery log:

[2020-02-26 14:11:40,765: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: intranet_project.tasks.add[xxxxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx]

Comment: If you do trigger your task and it still does not work, try and comment out this line "CELERY_TIMEZONE = TIME_ZONE" in your settings.py file

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a late response, but in order to check that celery info, now we need to use INFO

```
celery -A intranet_project worker -l INFO
```

instead of info

```
celery -A intranet_project worker -l info
```